# C++ Segmentation Fault - Core Dumped

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, segmentation-fault, coredump

I've been having this issue for a while now and I've searched about this type of error and I believe it has to do with a memory leak or a pointer that is pointing to nothing.

I've checked my code over and over again and I'm not able to find exactly where this issue is occurring as I don't know how to debug it. Even if I try and breakpoint the first line of the code, it will crash.

It is reading a bunch of ISBN's from a file and checking if they're valid or not.

Although it may seem like it's a lot, the logic is very simple.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <list>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Isbn
{
   private:
   string isbnCode;

   public:

   Isbn()
   {            
   }

   Isbn(string isbn): isbnCode(isbn)
   {               
   }

   ~Isbn()
   {              
   }

   string getIsbn()
   {
      return isbnCode;
   }

   void setIsbn(string input)
   {
      isbnCode = input;
   }
};

void setListOfIsbn(const string filename, list<Isbn> &listOfIsbn);
void validateIsbns(const list<Isbn> listOfIsbn, list<bool> &validations);
void printValidations(const list<Isbn> listOfIsbn, 
     const list<bool> validations);
string bToS(const bool bValue);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   list<Isbn> listOfIsbn;
   list<bool> validations;

   string inputFile = argv[1];

   setListOfIsbn(inputFile, listOfIsbn);
   validateIsbns(listOfIsbn, validations);
   printValidations(listOfIsbn, validations);

   return 0;
}

void setListOfIsbn(const string filename, list<Isbn> &listOfIsbn)
{
   list<Isbn>::const_iterator iterator;

   ifstream fin; 

   fin.open(filename.c_str()); 
   char ch;
   string isbnCode;

   while (!fin.eof()) 
   { 
      fin.get(ch);

      if (ch == '\n')
      {
         Isbn isbn;

         (isbn).setIsbn(isbnCode);
         listOfIsbn.push_back(isbn);
         isbnCode = "";         
      }
      else
      {
         isbnCode.append(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(ch));
      }
   } 
}

void validateIsbns(const list<Isbn> listOfIsbn, list<bool> &validations)
{
   list<Isbn>::const_iterator itr;

   for (itr = listOfIsbn.begin(); itr != listOfIsbn.end(); itr++)
   {
      Isbn isbn = *itr;
      string isbnCode = isbn.getIsbn();
      string isbnCodeReform = "";
      vector<int> products;
      int sumOfProducts = 0;
      unsigned int i;

      for (i = 0; i < isbnCode.length(); itr++)
      {
         if(isalnum(isbnCode[i]))
         {
            isbnCodeReform[i] = isbnCode[i];
         }
      }

      for (i = 0; i < (isbnCodeReform.length() - 1); itr++)
      {
         if(isbnCodeReform[i] == 'X')
         {
            isbnCodeReform[i] = 10;
         }         

         products[i] = isbnCodeReform[i] * (10 - i);      
      }

      vector<int>::const_iterator itr;

      for (itr = products.begin(); itr != products.end(); itr++)
      {
         sumOfProducts += products[*itr];
      }

      if ((sumOfProducts % 11) == 0)
      {
         validations.push_back(true);
      }
      else
      {
         validations.push_back(false);
      }
   }
}

void printValidations(const list<Isbn> listOfIsbn, 
     const list<bool> validations)
{
   list<Isbn>::const_iterator itr;
   list<bool>::const_iterator itr2 = validations.begin(); 

   for(itr = listOfIsbn.begin(); itr != listOfIsbn.end(); itr++)
   {
      string validate = bToS(*itr2);
      Isbn isbn = *itr;
      cout << isbn.getIsbn() + ": " + validate + "\n";
      itr2++;
   }
}

string bToS(const bool bValue)
{
   if(bValue == 0)
   {
      return "False";
   }
   else
   {
      return "True";
   }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You need a debugger to extract a stack trace, so you know where it's crashing.  What platform are you working on? GCC? MSVC?

Comment: So all this code and not even the original segfault error huh? Sure would be nice to narrow it down to, say, a specific method.

Comment: I never knew about valgrind, trying now, thanks

Comment: In rudimentary testing I see two crashes. The first one happens if you start the application without any command line argument. The second happens with an argument of "blah". Use your debugger -- preferably before posting to SO.

Comment: @WhozCraig: You don't have to harass him, he's new at this.  Just explain it to him.

Comment: Its hard for me to debug it as I'm compiling on a server and not my local machine. The server doesn't have gdb which is apparently the best way to find out exactly where it's faulting.

Comment: @JasonKing That a really tricky environment to do any kind of serious programming.  Consider scattering different `cerr << "Checkpoint xx";` lines throughout the code.  You can then narrow down where the crash occurred.  Output the values of relevant variables while you're at it.

Comment: There's nothing in this code that requires debugging it _on the server_. The code will compile and run elsewhere, including your local machine (which I presume you can put a debugger on).

Comment: @JasonKing What happens when you remove the `reinterpret_cast<>` I mentioned in the first comment? Having to do that is a screaming signal flare that something is dreadfully wrong *in the approach to solving problem X*. You question essentially asks whats wrong with this code, but what is baseline-wrong with it may very well be how it is attempting to solve the *actual* problem. Almost immediately things like `.eof()` as a loop condition in a C++ program signals "design flaw." Certainly we can help, but having some hard data would help *us*. Do you a *real* sample of the input file handy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've tried to detail as many of the obvious errors as I could below. There could be plenty more. With this many errors it obvious that you are taking the wrong approach to programming. Firstly you should think clearly about the code you are writing, it's not enough to write something that looks roughly right, with programming you have to get it *exactly* right. Secondly you are writing far too much low quality code. You should write a few lines of code, get those working before you write any more. You have piled error upon error here so it's obvious you have been doing zero testing. That's no way for even a professional to work, let alone a beginner. And working means working, not just compiling. As this code shows it's easy to write loads of code that compiles. Finally learn to use a debugger, it will help loads. Apparently you have some sort of complicated client/server set up. Just forget about that, install a compiler and debugger on your own machine.

```
isbnCode.append(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(ch));
```

is just wrong

```
isbnCode += ch;
```

is what you want. Don't use reinterpret_cast unless you really know what you are doing.

```
while (!fin.eof()) 
{ 
    fin.get(ch);
```

is the wrong way of checking for an end of file

```
while (fin.get(ch)) 
{
```

is what you want.

In fact the whole `void setListOfIsbn(const string filename, list<Isbn> &listOfIsbn)` is way too complicated. This does exactly the same but in three times less code

```
void setListOfIsbn(const string filename, list<Isbn> &listOfIsbn)
{
    ifstream fin(filename.c_str());
    string isbnCode;
    while (getline(fin, isbnCode))
        listOfIsbn.push_back(isbnCode);
}
```

This code is incorrect

```
  string isbnCodeReform = "";
  for (i = 0; i < isbnCode.length(); itr++)
  {
     if(isalnum(isbnCode[i]))
     {
        isbnCodeReform[i] = isbnCode[i];
     }
  }
```

because isbnCodeReform is a zero length string so `isbnCodeReform[i]` is going to fail. Probably you meant this

```
  string isbnCodeReform = "";
  for (i = 0; i < isbnCode.length(); itr++)
  {
     if(isalnum(isbnCode[i]))
     {
        isbnCodeReform.push_back(isbnCode[i]);
     }
  }
```

This is the same error

```
vector<int> products;
for (i = 0; i < (isbnCodeReform.length() - 1); itr++)
{
     if(isbnCodeReform[i] == 'X')
     {
        isbnCodeReform[i] = 10;
     }         

     products[i] = isbnCodeReform[i] * (10 - i);      
}
```

Again products is a zero length array, so `products[i]` will fail. Again you probably meant something like

```
     products.push_back(isbnCodeReform[i] * (10 - i));
```

This is a confusion about how iterators work

```
  for (itr = products.begin(); itr != products.end(); itr++)
  {
     sumOfProducts += products[*itr];
  }
```

You could write

```
  for (itr = products.begin(); itr != products.end(); itr++)
  {
     sumOfProducts += *itr;
  }
```

or you could write

```
  for (i = 0; i < products.size(); i++)
  {
     sumOfProducts += products[i];
  }
```

What you have is a mix of the two which doesn't work.

Comment: +/-0 is it better to give a person a fish or to teach that person to fish? I truly don't know which is better on SO, thus no vote.

Comment: @msw Well SO isn't really a good place to teach C++. I've tried to give some general advice as well as the specific errors.

Comment: +1. For both - giving a fish while teaching to fish.

Comment: @msw In fact, he made me realize stupid mistakes that I had made. I come from a c# background so I'm used to using [] brackets to assign and things like that. If you look at someones solution and you notice that they have a 1 + 1 = 3 in there, will you not tell them?

Comment: +1 as well. You would be hard-pressed to have a more detailed explanation of (a) what is wrong with the current approach, (b) *why* it is wrong, and (c) alternatives *with explanations* of better ways to solve the root problem X. Most of us learn by example, and the biggest problem with examples is often the "canned solution" of "this works" with no rhyme nor reasonable explanation of *why* this works. This answer provides both critical analysis and  *explained* alternatives, the latter generally the missing link in "just do this"-type answers. Thus this is worthy of the up-vote.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs here:

```
     isbnCode.append(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(ch));
```

Where you are casting a character (most likely a digit) to a `const char *` - so we have the value of a character, used as a pointer. Which is almost certain to fail on any system that has any memory access checking at all.

You should add the character to your string. Simplest way is:

```
     isbnCode += ch;
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help guys, pretty new to c++. implemented all your fixes and got it working. Cheers!